# Different Caches in the same cluster for Spring Cache using AWS ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-elasticache, spring-cache

I'm working my way through http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html to integrate Spring Cache into our AWS applications.

Can someone please explain to me how to correctly encapsulate different `@Cacheable` classes using the guide?

As far as I can tell, when you use `@EnableElastiCache` you need to specify the name of the the Elasticache cluster that create in AWS in the annotation:

```
@EnableElastiCache( @CacheClusterConfig( name = "myAwsCluster", expiration = 300 ) )
```

Then you *have* to use the same cluster name as the cache name in your `@Cacheable` class:

```
@Cacheable( "myAwsCluster" )
public String expensiveMethod()
```

Unless I've missed something, this completely breaks encapsulation as you have to tie the value on the annotation to the physical resource you create in AWS. Am I missing something, or is this the way that spring cloud expects you to work?

Furthermore, it means that you need to launch a seperate AWS ElastiCache cluster for each spring `Cache` class that you want to use, making it hugely expensive and prohibiting resource sharing.

```
@CacheConfig( "myAwsCluster" )
public class Class1
{
    @Cacheable
    public void something()
    {
        ...
    }
}

@CacheConfig( "mySecondAwsCluster" )
public class Class2
{
    @Cacheable
    public void somethingElse()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember - which probably means that I didn't find a solution. I think this was a short research problem that didn't go very far (otherwise I would have probably remembered)

Comment: For people in similar situation, I have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableElastiCache` encourages physical separation of caches, which may not what one needs all the time.

Instead of using `@EnableElastiCache`, use `@EnableCaching` for cache configuration. It can point to an `Elasticache`. Sample configuration for `Elasticache` with `Redis` cluster mode enabled.

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=<Elasticache Configuration endpoint>
```

Now you can use `@Cacheable` with the logical cache names.